# Installing PyGame onto Mountain Lion OS

Tags: python, macos, pygame, osx-mountain-lion

Okay, so I've completely given up.

I've tried about a thousand different walkthroughs to solve my problem, on every website I can find, but I either get stuck and no one knows the answer, or they just don't work.

So has anyone got an answer to installing PyGame onto Mountain Lion that they know 100% works and they can walk me through it as if I'm 6 years old?

I just want to run PyGame and this is driving me insane.

Cheers.

Comment: Python version? What have you tried? (Please be more specific)

Comment: Please accept the answer from @MattDMo. I came here with the same question and read all kinds of alternatives on this site and other sites. After much research, I found his answer to be the simplest and best. (I'm just trying to pay it forward to the next poor person to save them a lot of time!)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I'm running OSX 10.8.3 (Python 2.7.3), and I got pygame (1.9.1) up and running in about 15 minutes.

Here's what I did. I brewed my Python a long time ago, so I forget the steps there. I seem to remember editing some symbolic links in `\usr\local`. At any rate, I'll assume you can use google as well as I can to figure out what to do here.

1. download homebrew
2. `brew install python27` if you don't have it
3. `pip install numpy` if you don't have it.
4. `brew install sdl`
5. `brew install sdl_gfx sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf`
6. Download pygame v1.9.1 source for Unix architecture.
7. cp ~/Downloads/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz /tmp/pygame-1.9.1.tar.gz` or wherever. Go to that directory.
8. `sudo tar -xvf pygame-1.9.1.tar.gz`
9. `sudo python config.py` should fail with a hint to edit `Setup`
10. `sudo emacs Setup`, or your favorite text editor.
11. Look for the entries for SDL, FONT, IMAGE and MIXER.
12. Replace them with `SDL = -I/usr/local/include/SDL -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL`, `FONT = -lSDL_ttf`, `IMAGE = -lSDL_image`, and `MIXER = -lSDL_mixer`, respectively.
13. `cd src`, `emacs scale_mmx64.c`. Look for all occurrences of `movsxl` with `movslq`. You should find two occurrences.
14. `cd ..` and `sudo python setup.py install`

I only checked that I can load pygame from the prompt in Python, I didn't check anything else.

Refs:

http://jalada.co.uk/2011/06/17/installing-pygame-on-os-x-with-a-homebrew-python-2-7-install.html
[Error when Installing Pygame on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954497/error-when-installing-pygame-on-mountain-lion)

Comment: Just realized (most) 6 year olds probably don't know emacs key shortcuts :)

Comment: Great little tutorial! There's some words missing from step 13, that's the only thing that that can be improved with this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.com) installed, you can run `sudo port install pyXX-game` where XX is your macports python version from 24 to 27 and 31 to 32. This way it'll take care of all your dependencies automagically, and should theoretically work out of the box, assuming your system is set up to use macports python by default.

Comment: In order to avoid all kinds of potential trouble with 32-bit vs. 64-bit compatibility trouble I read about, and to get compatibility with my son's Raspberry Pi version of Python and Pygame, I successfully did the following, which only took a few minutes: on the RasPi, I ran `python --version` and `python -c "import pygame; print pygame.version.vernum"` (to get his version numbers), then on my Mac I ran `sudo port install py27-game`, to get the same versions. MacPorts pulled in the required version of Python automatically. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Here are my steps about how to install Pygame WITHOUT tweaking the config file + installing manually.

I'm running OSX 10.9.2 (Python 2.7.7), and I got pygame (1.9.2a0) up running just now.

Assume you already have **homebrew, python** and **pip** installed.

```
brew install libvorbis sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
brew install mercurial
# activate virtual env or use sudo:
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

[Pygame Official Answers](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install#comment-8540088)

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this problem and, at the moment, my pygame installation seems to be ok.

I first tried the Homebrew to install python (2.7.5) and pygame. After install them through Homebrew I was able to import pygame module on python console. But, when I tried to run a pygame application with some jpg images the error "pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file" occurred. This error meas that only BMP images can be used in pygame applications (not reazonable), and it seems it can be fixed by installing a previous binary of pygame for Mac OS X 10.3, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810834/pygame-error-file-is-not-a-windows-bmp-file-mac-osx). Since I installed it from the available Homebrew packages, I was not able to choose any version. For this case the solution given by BenDundee may solve the problem since he installed pygame with python.

I decided to try Macports to solve my problem. You can consult the page http://astrofrog.github.io/macports-python/ to get more information about python installation through Macports. After install python, assuming you install version 2.7.5, which package is python27, you should install py27-game package to get pygame.
This was the solution that really worked for me.